# How do I select the max of several fields in the middle of a one to many to many query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All,

I have this query below which is a one to many to many relationship.

The relationship is as such, a story can have multiple tasks (1>M) each task can have multiple time entries (M-M)

I want to get the 1st occurrence of 3 fields in the tasks section and null the remainder for each story. So for example;

```
Story 1234
Tasks 12, 13, 14,15
Time entry 120, 121, 134, 135 etc....
```

There are 3 fields in tasks OptimisticEstimate, ProbableEstimate and Pessimistic Estimate that get repeated at the task level when Time entry table is linked in to the query (as it should be).

I want to get the 1st occurrence of those fields for each task and leave any other occurrence NULL so that when we sum it up the estimated don't get summed along with the hours from time entry.

Hopefully that is clear.

```
WITH
WorkItem_CTE AS
    (-- Child Level (Task)
    SELECT   wi1.AreaID
            ,a.Name AS AreaName
            ,wi1.ProjectID
            ,wi1.IterationID
            -- Work Items
            ,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),wi1.CreatedDateUtc) AS WorkItemCreatedDTS
            ,wi1.WorkItemID
            ,wi1.[Type] AS WorkItemType
            ,wi1.Name AS WorkItemName
            ,wi1.[Status] AS WorkItemStatus
            ,wi1.[Priority] AS WorkItemPriority
            ,wi1.Complexity
            ,wi1.Estimate
            -- Tasks
            ,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),wi2.CreatedDateUtc) AS TaskCreatedDTS
            ,wi2.WorkItemID AS TaskID
            ,wi2.Name AS TaskName
            ,wi2.[Status] AS TaskStatus
            ,wi2.AssignedTo  AS TaskAssignedTo
            ,wi2.EstimateOptimistic
            ,Case When wi2.EstimateProbable IS NULL  Then (wi2.EstimateOptimistic + wi2.EstimatePessimistic)/2 Else wi2.EstimateProbable End As EstimateProbable
            ,wi2.EstimatePessimistic
            ,wi2.WorkCompleted
            ,wi2.WorkRemaining
    FROM    dbo.WorkItem wi1 WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN dbo.WorkItem wi2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON wi1.WorkItemID = wi2.ParentID
                AND wi2.[Status] <> 'Deleted'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Area a WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON wi1.AreaID = a.AreaID
            --LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Project p WITH (NOLOCK)
            --  ON wi1.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
    WHERE   wi1.[Status] <> 'Deleted'
    UNION ALL
    -- Parent level (Story, Bug, Feedback)
    SELECT   wi1.AreaID
            ,a.Name AS AreaName
            ,wi1.ProjectID
            ,wi1.IterationID
            -- Work Items
            ,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),wi1.CreatedDateUtc) AS WorkItemCreatedDTS
            ,wi1.WorkItemID
            ,wi1.[Type] AS WorkItemType
            ,wi1.Name AS WorkItemName
            ,wi1.[Status] AS WorkItemStatus
            ,wi1.[Priority] AS WorkItemPriority
            ,wi1.Complexity
            ,wi1.Estimate
            -- Tasks
            ,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),wi2.CreatedDateUtc) AS TaskCreatedDTS
            ,wi2.WorkItemID AS TaskID
            ,wi2.Name AS TaskName
            ,wi2.[Status] AS TaskStatus
            ,wi2.AssignedTo  AS TaskAssignedTo
            ,wi2.EstimateOptimistic
            ,Case When wi2.EstimateProbable IS NULL  Then (wi2.EstimateOptimistic + wi2.EstimatePessimistic)/2 Else wi2.EstimateProbable End As EstimateProbable
            ,wi2.EstimatePessimistic
            ,wi2.WorkCompleted
            ,wi2.WorkRemaining
    FROM    dbo.WorkItem wi1 WITH (NOLOCK)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.WorkItem wi2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON wi1.WorkItemID = wi2.ParentID
                AND wi2.[Status] <> 'Deleted'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Area a WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON wi1.AreaID = a.AreaID
    WHERE   wi1.[Type] <> 'Task'
    AND     wi1.[Status] <> 'Deleted'
    AND     wi2.ParentID IS NULL
    ),
--Time Entry for Tasks  
TimeEntry_CTE As
(SELECT te.WorkItemID
      ,te.ProjectID
      ,te.Date
      ,te.Hours
      ,te.CreatedBy
      ,te.CreatedDateUtc
      ,te.LastModifiedBy
      ,te.LastModifiedDateUtc
      ,te.Note
  FROM TimeEntry te
  ) 
SELECT   wi.AreaID
        ,wi.AreaName
        ,wi.ProjectID
        ,p.Name AS ProjectName
        ,wi.WorkItemCreatedDTS
        ,wi.WorkItemID
        ,wi.WorkItemType
        ,wi.WorkItemName
        ,wi.WorkItemStatus
        ,wi.WorkItemPriority
        ,wi.Complexity
        ,wi.Estimate AS StoryEstimate
        ,wi.TaskCreatedDTS
        ,wi.TaskID
        ,wi.TaskName
        ,wi.EstimateOptimistic
        ,wi.EstimateProbable
        ,wi.EstimatePessimistic
        ,wi.TaskStatus
        ,wi.TaskAssignedTo
        ,wi.WorkCompleted
        ,wi.WorkRemaining
        ,te.WorkItemID as TimeWorkItemID
        ,te.ProjectID
        ,te.Date
        ,te.Hours
        ,te.CreatedBy
        ,te.CreatedDateUtc
        ,te.LastModifiedBy
        ,te.LastModifiedDateUtc
        ,te.Note
FROM    WorkItem_CTE wi WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Project p WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON wi.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
        inner Join TimeEntry_CTE te With (nolock)
            ON wi.TaskID = te.WorkItemID
```

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Revised Code based on suggestions. Closer but not quite right.

```
WITH
WorkItem_CTE AS
    (-- Child Level (Task)
    SELECT   wi1.AreaID
            ,a.Name AS AreaName
            ,wi1.ProjectID
            ,wi1.IterationID
            -- Work Items
            ,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),wi1.CreatedDateUtc) AS WorkItemCreatedDTS
            ,wi1.WorkItemID
            ,wi1.[Type] AS WorkItemType
            ,wi1.Name AS WorkItemName
            ,wi1.[Status] AS WorkItemStatus
            ,wi1.[Priority] AS WorkItemPriority
            ,wi1.Complexity
            ,wi1.Estimate
            -- Tasks
            ,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),wi2.CreatedDateUtc) AS TaskCreatedDTS
            ,wi2.WorkItemID AS TaskID
            ,wi2.Name AS TaskName
            ,wi2.[Status] AS TaskStatus
            ,wi2.AssignedTo  AS TaskAssignedTo
            ,wi2.EstimateOptimistic
            ,Case When wi2.EstimateProbable IS NULL  Then (wi2.EstimateOptimistic + wi2.EstimatePessimistic)/2 Else wi2.EstimateProbable End As EstimateProbable
            ,wi2.EstimatePessimistic
            ,wi2.WorkCompleted
            ,wi2.WorkRemaining
    FROM    dbo.WorkItem wi1 WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN dbo.WorkItem wi2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON wi1.WorkItemID = wi2.ParentID
                AND wi2.[Status] <> 'Deleted'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Area a WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON wi1.AreaID = a.AreaID
            --LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Project p WITH (NOLOCK)
            --  ON wi1.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
    WHERE   wi1.[Status] <> 'Deleted'
    UNION ALL
    -- Parent level (Story, Bug, Feedback)
    SELECT   wi1.AreaID
            ,a.Name AS AreaName
            ,wi1.ProjectID
            ,wi1.IterationID
            -- Work Items
            ,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),wi1.CreatedDateUtc) AS WorkItemCreatedDTS
            ,wi1.WorkItemID
            ,wi1.[Type] AS WorkItemType
            ,wi1.Name AS WorkItemName
            ,wi1.[Status] AS WorkItemStatus
            ,wi1.[Priority] AS WorkItemPriority
            ,wi1.Complexity
            ,wi1.Estimate
            -- Tasks
            ,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),wi2.CreatedDateUtc) AS TaskCreatedDTS
            ,wi2.WorkItemID AS TaskID
            ,wi2.Name AS TaskName
            ,wi2.[Status] AS TaskStatus
            ,wi2.AssignedTo  AS TaskAssignedTo
            ,wi2.EstimateOptimistic
            ,Case When wi2.EstimateProbable IS NULL  Then (wi2.EstimateOptimistic + wi2.EstimatePessimistic)/2 Else wi2.EstimateProbable End As EstimateProbable
            ,wi2.EstimatePessimistic
            ,wi2.WorkCompleted
            ,wi2.WorkRemaining
    FROM    dbo.WorkItem wi1 WITH (NOLOCK)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.WorkItem wi2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON wi1.WorkItemID = wi2.ParentID
                AND wi2.[Status] <> 'Deleted'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Area a WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON wi1.AreaID = a.AreaID
    WHERE   wi1.[Type] <> 'Task'
    AND     wi1.[Status] <> 'Deleted'
    AND     wi2.ParentID IS NULL
    ),
--Time Entry for Tasks  
TimeEntry_CTE As
(SELECT te.WorkItemID
      ,te.ProjectID
      ,te.Date
      ,te.Hours
      ,te.CreatedBy
      ,te.CreatedDateUtc
      ,te.LastModifiedBy
      ,te.LastModifiedDateUtc
      ,te.Note
  FROM TimeEntry te
  ),
wi_CTE As 
(SELECT  wi.AreaID
        ,wi.AreaName
        ,wi.ProjectID
        ,p.Name AS ProjectName
        ,wi.WorkItemCreatedDTS
        ,wi.WorkItemID
        ,wi.WorkItemType
        ,wi.WorkItemName
        ,wi.WorkItemStatus
        ,wi.WorkItemPriority
        ,wi.Complexity
        ,wi.Estimate AS StoryEstimate
        ,wi.TaskCreatedDTS
        ,wi.TaskID
        ,wi.TaskName
        ,wi.EstimateOptimistic
        ,wi.EstimateProbable
        ,wi.EstimatePessimistic
        ,wi.TaskStatus
        ,wi.TaskAssignedTo
        ,wi.WorkCompleted
        ,wi.WorkRemaining
        ,te.WorkItemID as TimeWorkItemID
        ,te.ProjectID TimeProjectID
        ,te.Date
        ,Sum(te.Hours) Hours
        ,te.CreatedBy
        ,te.CreatedDateUtc
        ,te.LastModifiedBy
        ,te.LastModifiedDateUtc
        ,te.Note
FROM    WorkItem_CTE wi WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Project p WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON wi.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
        inner Join TimeEntry_CTE te With (nolock)
            ON wi.TaskID = te.WorkItemID

--where wi.WorkItemID =94

Group By
         wi.AreaID
        ,wi.AreaName
        ,wi.ProjectID
        ,p.Name
        ,wi.WorkItemCreatedDTS
        ,wi.WorkItemID
        ,wi.WorkItemType
        ,wi.WorkItemName
        ,wi.WorkItemStatus
        ,wi.WorkItemPriority
        ,wi.Complexity
        ,wi.Estimate 
        ,wi.TaskCreatedDTS
        ,wi.TaskID
        ,wi.TaskName
        ,wi.EstimateOptimistic
        ,wi.EstimateProbable
        ,wi.EstimatePessimistic
        ,wi.TaskStatus
        ,wi.TaskAssignedTo
        ,wi.WorkCompleted
        ,wi.WorkRemaining
        ,te.WorkItemID
        ,te.ProjectID
        ,te.Date
        ,te.Hours
        ,te.CreatedBy
        ,te.CreatedDateUtc
        ,te.LastModifiedBy
        ,te.LastModifiedDateUtc
        ,te.Note),

cte AS (SELECT wi_cte.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WorkItemID, TaskID ORDER BY TimeWorkItemID) RN
              FROM wi_CTE
              )
SELECT 
         AreaID
        ,AreaName
        ,ProjectID
        ,ProjectName
        ,WorkItemCreatedDTS
        ,WorkItemID
        ,WorkItemType
        ,WorkItemName
        ,WorkItemStatus
        ,WorkItemPriority
        ,Complexity
        ,StoryEstimate 
        ,TaskCreatedDTS
        ,TaskID
        ,TaskName
        ,EstimateOptimistic
        ,EstimateProbable
        ,EstimatePessimistic
        ,TaskStatus
        ,TaskAssignedTo
        ,WorkCompleted
        ,WorkRemaining
        ,WorkItemID
        ,ProjectID
        ,Date
        ,Hours
        ,CreatedBy
        ,CreatedDateUtc
        ,LastModifiedBy
        ,LastModifiedDateUtc
        ,Note
        ,RN
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Hours END) AS SumTime
FROM cte
Where RN=1
GROUP BY 
 AreaID
        ,AreaName
        ,ProjectID
        ,ProjectName
        ,WorkItemCreatedDTS
        ,WorkItemID
        ,WorkItemType
        ,WorkItemName
        ,WorkItemStatus
        ,WorkItemPriority
        ,Complexity
        ,StoryEstimate 
        ,TaskCreatedDTS
        ,TaskID
        ,TaskName
        ,EstimateOptimistic
        ,EstimateProbable
        ,EstimatePessimistic
        ,TaskStatus
        ,TaskAssignedTo
        ,WorkCompleted
        ,WorkRemaining
        ,WorkItemID
        ,ProjectID
        ,Date
        ,Hours
        ,CreatedBy
        ,CreatedDateUtc
        ,LastModifiedBy
        ,LastModifiedDateUtc
        ,Note
        ,RN
```

What I get

```
ProjectID   ProjectName WorkItemID  WorkItemType    WorkItemName    EstimateOptimistic  EstimateProbable    EstimatePessimistic RN  SumTime
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   1   8
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   2   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   3   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   4   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   1   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   2   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   3   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   4   8
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   5   3



What I'm Looking for                                    
ProjectID   ProjectName WorkItemID  WorkItemType    WorkItemName    EstimateOptimistic  EstimateProbable    EstimatePessimistic RN  SumTime
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   1   8
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   NULL    NULL    NULL    2   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   NULL    NULL    NULL    3   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   NULL    NULL    NULL    4   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   2   3   4   1   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   NULL    NULL    NULL    2   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   NULL    NULL    NULL    3   4
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   NULL    NULL    NULL    4   8
11  Data Group  94  Story   Backlog Report with new logic   NULL    NULL    NULL    5   3
```

Hopefully that helps clarify what I'm trying for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a conditional `SUM()` and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Let's say the query above outputs data like this:

```
Story, Task, TimeEntry
1234, 12, 120
1234, 12, 121
1234, 12, 134
1234, 13, 135
1234, 13, 120
1234, 13, 121
1234, 13, 134
1234, 14, 135
1234, 14, 120
1234, 14, 121
1234, 14, 134
1234, 14, 135
```

You could use this:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Story, Task ORDER BY TimeEntry) RN
              FROM Table1
              )
SELECT Story, Task, SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN TimeEntry END) AS SumTime
FROM cte
GROUP BY Story, Task
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbf5d/2/0)

Each line will be numbered, starting at 1 for each combination of `Story` and `Task`, allowing you to use the condition of `RN = 1` to avoid aggregating duplicate lines.  Since you said the values repeat it doesn't matter what you put in the `ORDER BY` clause for your `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. Not sure where in my query to put it however. I'm already using a CTE.

Comment: You could encapsulate your existing query in another cte, or perhaps you could add the `ROW_NUMBER()` to your TimeEntry_CTE and alter the `JOIN` to include `AND RN = 1`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting closer. I added the CTE you suggested to the end of the existing query as well as a select for that CTE where RN = 1 and It certainly filtered the entries, but by too much.

Now instead of getting all the time entries with the just one Estimate filled in and the rest null, I'm just getting the Time Entries with RN = 1. I'm going to post the revised SQL code in the Original question since I don't have the room in the comments for it.